# How do I reverse an array

Tags: arrays, coldfusion

Hi I have an array of strings, and I need to output them from the last one to the first one.

I don't see an `arrayReverse()` function, but I'm only just learning ColdFusion

Comment: CFLib to the rescue! Someone has already written an `arrayReverse` function: http://www.cflib.org/udf/ArrayReverse

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just loop over the array in reverse

```
<cfloop index="i" from="#arrayLen(myArray)#" to="1" step="-1">
   <cfoutput>#myArray[i]#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

I think you need to use Java methods to really reverse the array.

```
<cfscript>
// and for those who use cfscript:
for ( var i = arrayLen( myArray ); i >= 1; i-- ) {
    writeOutput( myArray[i] );
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: If all you are doing is outputting the values, looping backwards through the array like this is what you need

Comment: The java method is quick and easy also if you have access to java on your host:  <cfscript>
      a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      createObject("java", "java.util.Collections").reverse(a);
      writeDump(a); 
    </cfscript>

Answer (score 2):

FYI array in CF is just an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), so...

```
arr = [1,2,3];
createObject("java", "java.util.Collections").reverse(arr);
writeDump(arr);   // arr becomes [3,2,1]
```

And I would not bother writing `arrayReverse()` because array is passed by value in CF (not until CF2016's `this.passArraybyReference`) so it's super inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Oh but there is an ArraySort method!

`ArraySort( array, sort_type [, sort_order] );`

Returns boolean.

`array` is updated by reference.

`sort_type` can be `numeric`, `text` or `textnocase`

`sort_order` can be `asc` or `desc`

```
<cfscript>
test = [ "c", "d", "a", "b" ];
arraySort( test, 'textnocase' );

test is now:
[ "a", "b", "c", "d" ]

</cfscript>
```

Check out the documentation here:

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arraysort.html

Comment: I know he says arraySort, but he asks how to reverse the array and not sort it. Good solution, if the original array is sorted otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Though this guy does not need it, [java.util.Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29) works well for reversing

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function to reverse an array. It modifies the array and returns it.

```
function init(required array arr) {
    var arrLen = arrayLen(arr);
    for (var i = 1; i <= (arrLen / 2); i++) {
        var swap = arr[arrLen + 1 - i];
        arr[arrLen + 1 - i] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = swap;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I've tested it, and it works on arrays of strings, as well as objects, etc.

```
writeOutput(arrayReverse(['a','b','c']) ); // => ['c', 'b', 'a']

var a = ['apple', 'ball', 'cat', 'dog'];
arrayReverse(a);
writeOutput(a); // => ['dog', 'cat', 'ball', 'apple']
```

I put it into it's own component, so it's easier to use in different projects.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfscript>
    test = [ "a", "b", "c", "d" ];
    writeDump(listToArray(reverse(arrayToList(test))));
</cfscript>
```

Will do the trick.

Comment: Fine for small arrays - but expensive for big ones

Comment: Nice idea if the data within the array is simple. Wouldn't work if its an array of objects or structs or arrays.

Comment: Try your example with words instead of single characters. It really does reverse.

Comment: If `test = ['hello', 'cat']` then you'll get `['tac', 'olleh']`.